vue "InternalError: too much recursion"
I try to embedd chart.js as a vue component into my app.
As soon as i try to add new data to the chart dataset i get the error:
Uncaught InternalError: too much recursion
    push reactivity.esm-bundler.js:798
    value helpers.collection.ts:138
    noTracking reactivity.esm-bundler.js:901
    push reactivity.esm-bundler.js:799
    value helpers.collection.ts:138
    noTracking reactivity.esm-bundler.js:901
    push reactivity.esm-bundler.js:799
    value helpers.collection.ts:138
    noTracking reactivity.esm-bundler.js:901
    push reactivity.esm-bundler.js:799
    value helpers.collection.ts:138
    noTracking reactivity.esm-bundler.js:901


App.vue
<script>
import Chart from "./Chart.vue";

export default {
    name: "Chart Demo",
    components: {
        Chart
    },
    data() {
        return {};
    }
};
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <Chart></Chart>
    </div>
</template>

Chart.vue
<template>
    <canvas ref="canvas"></canvas>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { Chart } from "chart.js/auto";

export default defineComponent({
    data() {
        return {
            chart: null,
            chartData: {
                labels: [
                    "Januar", 
                    "Februar", 
                    "März", 
                    "April", 
                    "Mai", 
                    "Juni", 
                    "Juli", 
                    "August"
                ],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Verkäufe",
                    data: [60, 65, 67, 65, 66, 69, 72, 70]
                }]
            }
        };
    },
    mounted() {

        console.log("mounted create")

        this.chart = new Chart(this.$refs.canvas, {
            type: "line",
            data: this.chartData
        });

        setInterval(() => {

            console.log("Add chart data")

            let d = 90
            this.chartData.labels.push(d);
            this.chartData.datasets[0].data.push(d);

        }, 3000);

    }
});
</script>

Without this part:
setInterval(() => {

            console.log("Add chart data")

            let d = 90
            this.chartData.labels.push(d);
            this.chartData.datasets[0].data.push(d);

        }, 3000);

it just works fine.
But i would like to create a history of values, where i need to add new data to the chart and re-render it.
What is the correct way to manipulate the chart data and re render it?
Minimal reproducible example playground

Try to not make chartData reactive in data(). e.g. created() { this.chartData = {...}.

@EstusFlask This approach add the data, but as soon as i call this.chart.update() to re render, the same error message appears.

Try to do the same for this.chart instead. Generally chartData could be kept reactive, especially if you want to watch it for update() calls. But random objs shouldn't be made reactive without a reason, this affects how they work. If the problem persists, please, provide a way to reproduce, it needs to be debugged

Do you know how to provide a playground snippet? I wanted to put it on https://play.vuejs.org/ but couldnt add chart.js as dependency. You tipp with this.chart did also not work.

Try stackblitz or codesandbox

@EstusFlask minimal reproducible example playground link added at the end of the post.

Thanks. This won't happen if both are not reactive https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-x8knwbcc

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Sorry, I don't use SO chats, they have problems with notifications, comments are more useful for that

@EstusFlask I need a possibility to pass the chart data as props from the parent component and render the chart. As soon as i pass the object as props, i get the same error again.

@Bravo How? In ff i get the error above, in chrome "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Oops, sorry, for some reason I didn't get the error last time!

This is a known issue with Chart.js. It patches data array to track changes similarly to how Vue (2.x specifically) does this, this interferes with Vue reactivity and can result in a recursion that that this warning indicates. There's no way to reliably disable this behaviour except by patching or extending builtin Chart.js controllers. Or providing a read-only sealed array, but this will prevent Vue reactivity from working, and cloning data to satisfy both would be inefficient.
So it's better to provide Chart.js instance with non-reactive data. In case data object reference changes through the component lifecycle, this needs to be additionally handled. Given data is a prop that is mutated in parent component, and chart is not reactive, it would be:
  created() {
    this.chart = null;
  },
  watch: {
    data: {
      deep: true,
      handler(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal)
          this chart.data = newVal;

        this.chart.update();
      },
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.chart = new Chart(this.$refs.canvas, {
      type: 'line',
      data: toRaw(this.data),
    });
  }

